# JavaScript states and statements

Tags: javascript, state, statements

Sorry about the title, I couldn't really think of a proper title in regards to my issue.

So currently, I have a functional code that works fine, but I have this slight issue that I can't seem to tackle.

Basically, I add an action, say north, and then a text will be displayed saying that you enter a church, do you want to explore? And then you get two options: Yes and No.

If you chose yes, a text will be displayed saying that you entered the church and long story short, you escape a near-death experience as the player

If you chose no and retreat, it will say you retreated the church safely. But the problem is after I choose a yes or no option for this instance, I can't seem to put in anything else in the input box to continue my actions to go south, west, east, or even north again. Instead, nothing happens. What I'd like to happen is, after the player gets the message of, "You retreated the church safely", instead of coming at a dead end of being restricted to type, the input box isn't restricted and functions normally like it did before you decided to enter the church. I hope you get what I mean. If you don't, simply type this in the input box:
-North
-Yes
-Retreat

and then try typing in an action after that, like "North". Nothing happens. What I'd like to happen is, the ability to continue onwards any direction the player chooses.

Here's the code:

...

```
        else if (newInput == "North") {
            textInput = "you went to the Abandoned Church. Do you explore?";
            state = "sites"
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = textInput;
        }

    } else if (state == "sites") {
        // Handle commands when game state is in "store"
        if (newInput == "No") {
        textInput = "You decided not to explore the church";
            state = "sites"
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = textInput;


        } else if (newInput == "Yes") {
            textInput = "You decided to explore the church and found and found that there were two zombies roaming around. They haven't noticed you. Do you still stay or retreat?";
            state = "zombies"
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = textInput;
        } else if (newInput == "No") {
            // Change the state to something else
        }

    } else if (state == "zombies") {
        // Handle commands when game state is in "dragon"

        if (newInput == "Stay And Explore") {
            textInput = "You decided to stay but it didn't take long for the zombies to notice you. Right in the nick of time, you managed to escape, shutting the doors behind you.";
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = textInput;
        } else if (newInput == "Retreat") {
            textInput = "You retreated the church safely. Where do you go now?";
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = textInput;
        }
        if (newInput = "Retreat") {
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = textInput;
          //UNDEFINED! <--When I type North after Retreat, it comes as Undefined, I don't know if I was close to coming to a solution in what I wanted which was to take the player back to the action they were on before which was North and are free to change their action and to head to any other location.

        }

    }
}
```

...

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

for a start:

```js
const inSelect =  document.getElementById('select-input')
  ,   btGo     =  document.getElementById('bt-go')
  ,   message  =  document.getElementById('message')
  ,   stateText =
        { 'init': { 'Help1': { next:'init', txt:'[Page 1 of 2. Type \'Help2\' for page 2] Commands you....' }
                  , 'Help2': { next:'sites', txt:'[Page 2 of 2] Commands you can use: <li>North One More</li><li ....' }
                  , 'South': { next:'sites', txt:'You went to abandoned city street 3' }
                  , 'South Again': { next:'sites', txt:'You went to abandoned city street 3' }
                  }
        , 'sites': { 'No': { next:'sites', txt:'You decided not to explore the church' }
                   , 'Yes': { next:'zombies', txt:'You decided to explore the church and found .......' }
                  }
        }


var state = 'init';

makeInSelect(state)

function makeInSelect( newState )
  {
  inSelect.innerHTML = ''
  for (let inp of Object.keys(stateText[newState]) )
    {
    inSelect.add(new Option(inp,inp)) 
    }
  }

btGo.onclick=_=>
  {
  let nextCase = stateText[state][inSelect.value]

  state = nextCase.next
  message.innerHTML = nextCase.txt

  makeInSelect(state)
  }
```

```html
<div id="message">...</div>

<select   id="select-input"></select>

<button id="bt-go"> GO </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you retreat from the church you are not setting your state variable to it's original value ("init"). That's why typing "North" has no effect; it is still in the "zombies" state and there is no "North" option in the zombies else-if.

Another possible problem with your code is that your are not exiting the function after a message is displayed. For example, after you type "Yes" in the "sites" state, the state is changed to "zombies" and all of the code in the "zombies" else-if is also executed - which is not what you want as if the "zombies" state has "Yes" it will also get executed. You need to return after a message is displayed. Also, consider using a switch statement, as they are more suited for this type of flow.

On a more general note writing a long chain of else-if statement can quickly get overwhelming. Consider implementing a state machine. For example, create an object for each state with an array of possible commands, messages for each command and the next state to which it takes you.

```js
let states = {
  "sites": {  
    commands: [
      {
        input: "yes",
        msg: "You decided to explore the church and found and found that there were two zombies roaming around. They haven't noticed you. Do you still stay or retreat?",
        next: "zombies"
      }
     ]
  },
  "zombies": {
    commands: [
      {
        input: "retreat",
        msg: "You retreated the church safely. Where do you go now?",
        next: "init"
      }
    ]
  }
}

let state = 'sites'

// just for illustration
function button() {
  let command = states[state].commands.find(command => command.input = newInput);
  
  if (typeof command === 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = `${newInput} is not a valid command`;
    return;
  }
  
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = command.msg;
  state = command.next;
}
```

That way you can make your game more scalable.